# Is this JSDoc? What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, jsdoc, doclet

I'm using NetBeans with the HTML5 project archetype.

One of the autogenerated documentation blocks for my function (after typing  /** <enter>) contains the following line:

- @type @exp;generateErrorClass@pro;ctor|Function

The referent line is:

var UnmodifiableProxyError = generateErrorClass('UnmodifiableProxyError');

So, this is JSDoc, right?   But I can't find any documentation that explains those @exp and @pro tags.   Can someone identify and explain that line of documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans can't always know type of variable in JavaScript and the `@exp;generateErrorClass@pro;ctor` is some internal type as resolved by NetBeans. Just replace it with whatever you want :)